# Polymer defining properties in element

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, polymer, web-component

While going through Polymer docs, I found two ways of defining properties in custom elements, namely:

```
Polymer('my-element', {
    myProp: 'someValue'
});
```

and

```
Polymer('my-element', {
    ready: function () {
        this.myProp = 'someValue';
    }
});
```

I understand that the first one passes the object as the prototype to my custom element, so the attribute exists before the element is created, while the other one waits for the element to be initialized before declaring the property.

I am wondering what are the differences between those two (if any), and when one would use over the other? Also are there any other ways of initializing properties/functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the default value in the `created()` callback for property values that are objects or arrays. Otherwise, you can get into a "shared state" problem in your objects. Setting values inside `created()` ensures that a separate object is created for each instance of the element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <script>
    Polymer({
      created: function() {
        // Creates `myObj` for *this* instance.
        this.myObj = {
          color: 'red'
        };
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And I prefer put the initialization code inside `created()`, rather than in `ready()`. See 
https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods for the difference between when the two callbacks fire.

To answer your other question: "Also are there any other ways of initializing properties/functions?". Yes, you can publish properties on an element. Example:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <h1>{{val}}</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      publish: {
        val: 'foo'
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

If you use the element like this, `val` is set to "foo":

```
<my-element></my-element>
```

If you use it like this, `val` is set to "bar":

```
<my-element val="bar"></my-element>
```

You can also declare attributes directly on a `<polymer-element>`. These automatically get included on each instance of the element. For example:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" foo="bar">
  <template>
    <h1 id="myHeading"></h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        this.$.myHeading.textContent = this.getAttribute('foo');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Note that in this case, you need to use `ready()`.

And of course you can set arbitrary attributes directly on an instance of a `<polymer-element>`:

```
<my-element disabled></my-element>
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains alot. Can you tell me how those arbitrary attributes work? What values do they pass to my custom element? Can I somehow define custom elements that are just attributes, the same way as I can define angularjs directives that are just attributes?

Comment: Arbitrary attributes work on Polymer elements just as they do on any HTML element. While you can do a lot with attributes, it is better Polymer design to work with published attributes (using `published` or `attributes=`). Think of published attributes as public interface for your element.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, though I was wondering about use cases such as, the animations (transitions) library, that could animate fade-in's or fade-out's of an element, and be used on any arbitrary element (for example a div) as an attribute. Something like this can be done with angular, and I am wondering if it can be done with Polymer? Or is it a better practice to create a custom element, that will just extend the "animation-element"?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the first example sets the property on the prototype object. The second example, on the other hand, sets the property on an *instance of the element*.
In vanilla javascript, the first example will translate into this:

```
var F = function () {};
F.prototype.myProp = 'someValue';
```

While the second will translate into something similar to this:

```
var F = function () {
    this.myProp = 'someValue';
};
```

It is *highly recommended* to avoid your first example, unless you know what you are doing. Setting properties on the prototype might have unexpected consequences. Take for example this piece of code:

```
Polymer('my-element', {
    myConfig: {
        myProp: 'someValue'
    }
});

var el1 = document.createElement('my-element'),
    el2 = document.createElement('my-element');

el1.myConfig.myProp = 'anotherValue';
console.debug(el2.myConfig.myProp); // will output 'anotherValue'
```

You can see that even though I am printing `el2.myConfig.myProp`, it is the same value as set on `el1.myConfig.myProp`. This happens due to the nature of [Prototypal Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: The reason you get `another` value for both elements is because they are referring to the same object. If you try it with `myConfig: 'someValue'`, the problem you are pointing at will disappear.